# How can I make a random gradient in CSS?

Tags: html, css, gradient

I am re-designing my school's website. I am trying to have a random gradient(like in the Insta logo). I already have the colors, but I don't just want a plain linear-gradient.

```css
.instagram {
  background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, #feda75, #fa7e1e, #d62976, #962fbf, #4f5bd5);
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="instagram"><i class="fa-brands fa-instagram"></i></div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I don't just want a plain linear-gradient"??

Comment: What do you mean by "random gradient"?

Comment: If you really want something random, ie that changes each time, you’ll have to use JavaScript to choose the colors and offsets as CSS does not have a random property.

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. You'd need to ask something more specific about your attempt.

Comment: FYI, "random" doesn't mean what most people seem to think it means, and it's unlikely to result in something visually appealing. Perhaps you meant "arbitrary", "specific", or "custom".

Answer (score 1):

Achieving the "randomness" like the gradient in the Instagram logo isn't very easy to do with html and css. It has linear and radial gradients mixed, with some other colors splashed around. It would be better to recreate the background in Gimp or Photoshop as an image and then use the image as the `background-image` to the div.

Comment: You came to the same conclusion I did about gradient types. It could be done, therefore, with overlapping (pseudo-)elements having reduced opacity.